# which checkbutton has been checked

Tags: python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

I have created a checkbox. I want the program prints 'python' when I  tick it in created checkbox.
but it doesn't work...I don't get error but it doesn't print 'python'
please help.
this is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
class Checkbar(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.vars = []
      for pick in picks:
         var = IntVar()
         chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
         chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
         self.vars.append(var)
   def state(self):
      return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)
   def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.vars[key]


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   lng = Checkbar(root, ['Python', 'Ruby', 'Perl', 'C++'])
   tgl = Checkbar(root, ['English','German'])
   lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=X)
   tgl.pack(side=LEFT)
   lng.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=2)


   def allstates(): 

##      print(lng[0])

      if lng[0] == 1:
         print ('python')


   Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)
   Button(root, text='Peek', command=allstates).pack(side=RIGHT)
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`lng[0]` is an `IntVar`, not an `int`, so it's never equal to one.

You need to use the `get` method to compare the value of the variable to 1:

```
def allstates(): 
    if lng[0].get() == 1:
        print ('python')
```

Another solution is to change the `__getitem__` method of the `Checkbar` so that it returns the value of the variable instead of the variable itself as I proposed in answer to [Python Form: Using TKinter --> run script based on checked checkboxes in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573292/python-form-using-tkinter-run-script-based-on-checked-checkboxes-in-gui/41574093#41574093)

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.vars[key].get()
```

In this case, you don't have to change the `allstates` function.

Comment: now if i want to use the variable ''lng[0]'' and its value in another class.what shoud i do?

Comment: I think `if lng[0].get():` is a more pythonic way to write codes than `if lng[0].get() == 1:`